# Android bluetooth crashing application

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-bluetooth

Having some trouble using `device.getName()`. It's for some reason causing my application to crash.

What I'm doing is displaying an adapter (holding bluetooth names) in a dialogue box. When I run the application and adding `device.getAdress()` instead of - `.getName()` the application works fine, but when doing it with `.getName()` it crashes.

```
mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            toothadapter.add(device.getName());
            toothadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(bluetooth.this);
builder.setTitle("Nearby Devices:");
builder.setAdapter(toothadapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Really need some help as to why this is happening.
The code above this, is all included in `onCreate()` within a `buttonListener`.

Comment: What's the type of `toothadapter`?

Comment: toothadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(bluetooth.this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item);

Comment: Can't - that's a major part of the problem, can't get my s7 edge to work with debugging, and can't emulate bt, as machine doesnt have -.-

Comment: You may have `NPE` calling `toothadapter.add()`. Log or `Toast` the return value of `device.getName()`.

Comment: Toast results:
"" / empty toast |
Samsung [Speaker] |
"" / empty toast |
"" / empty toast |
"" / empty toast |
DESKTOP-tl82

Comment: Did you use `Toast.makeText(...,device.getName(),...)` or `Toast.makeText(...,"" + device.getName(),...)`? Try the 1st one.

Comment: Bare with me, generating signed apk each time, and android update just landed on my phone (my luck rofl). If you have android, you can download at https://ufile.io/a2a1010 login with u: admin, p: admin. From here press "bluetooth" button and just press either of the list elements, and toasts will start coming. This version is with your 1st suggestion in above comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124173/discussion-between-onik-and-rasmus-hjorth-ludeking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Really need some help as to why this is happening.

It is hardly possible to say for sure what causes the app crash without seeing the stacktrace.

However note that [BluetoothDevice.getName()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getName()) returns `null` if *"there was a problem"*. And we know (from the `Toast` notifications you get) that the method returns `null`s in the app. These `null`s may or may not be the reason of the crash.

In addition, the place where `null` device name cannot cause `NPE` is `ArrayAdapter`. When you call `new ArrayAdapter<String>(Context, int)` the following [constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.%3Cinit%3E%28android.content.Context%2Cint%29) is invoked:

```
public ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    init(context, resource, 0, new ArrayList<T>());
}
```

Data structure used to store your data is `ArrayList` whose [`add()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.add%28java.lang.Object%29)'s method implementation allows adding `null` as opposed to the `List<>`'s [`add()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/List.java#List.add%28java.lang.Object%29) method declaration.

Comment: @Rasmus Hjorth Lüdeking I'll edit the answer upon a new info regarding the crash.